# Can't declare class symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

i got a little error trying to implement a MaintenanceListener service, who will display a maintenance page
Here's my services.yml

````
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in Cocorico\CoreBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name

#    Cocorico\CoreBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\:
#        resource: '../../src/Cocorico/CoreBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/*'


    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests,Event}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
#    AppBundle\Controller\:
#        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
#        public: true
#        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more services, or override services that need manual wiring
    # AppBundle\Service\ExampleService:
    #     arguments:
    #         $someArgument: 'some_value'
    maintenance_listener:
        class: AppBundle\Event\MaintenanceListener
        arguments:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }```
````

Here's my class:

```
<?php


namespace MListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $event->setResponse(new Response('Iziparty is in maintenance mode', Response::HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE));
        $event->stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

and here's the error i get:
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class MListener\MListener, because the name is already in use in /var/www/Symfony/src/AppBundle/Event/MaintenanceListener.php on line 9" while reading response header from upstream
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it all comes down to autoload magic. The autoload magic assumes a certain directory structure, that is (among other things) defined in composer.json. It essentially says:

namespace `AppBundle\...` is in directory `src/AppBundle/...`

and every class `AppBundle\Something\Else` is therefore located in `src/AppBundle/Something/Else.php`

now, symfony starts to load the service that is supposed to handle an event (due to your configuration) `AppBundle\Event\MaintenanceListener`, which it tries to instantiate, which leads to the auto loader loading the file `src/AppBundle/Event/MaintenanceListener.php` which only contains the class `MListener/MListener`.

Since auto-loading is a bit hacky, usually, it will try other approaches / definitions and possibly try to read that file again and it'll then fail to re-declare the `MListener/MListener` class, since it already exists.

Just to be explicit about this: These approaches work very well if standards are followed (specifically PSR-4 in this case), which bind the directory structure to namespace structure. If you put something in a file, that - according to PSR-4 - doesn't belong there, you gonna get problems, like the one you got.

The fix is easy and obvious: namespace is the directory (with backslash instead of whatever directory separator your OS has), filename is the classname (without .php obviously). So either, rename your file to `src/MListener/MListener.php` and adapt the services.yaml accordingly: `MListener\Mlistener: ...` or you rename your namespace and class in that file to `AppBundle\Event` and `MaintenanceListener` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to create the file src/Event/MaintenanceListener.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Event;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MaintenanceListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $event->setResponse(new Response('Iziparty is in maintenance mode', Response::HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE));
        $event->stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

With same name declared in the file service.yaml